# Apply iptables rules but exclude list of IPs

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I am going to apply the following iptables rule to temporarily ban every IP requests certain port(s) more than 30 times per minute.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25461 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name temporary --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 30/minute -j DROP
```

How can I sort-of whitelist a list of IP addresses, to be able to send and receive data from my server without any problem coming from the above rule? I need a rule that will leave certain IPs do whatever they do until now that I haven't any filter set. Ty.

Comment: Just add a rule just before this, with the whitelisted address and no rate-limiting, and ACCEPT. The order of rule is : the first match wins ! If you have many addresses, look for ipset (-m set --match-set LIST src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put rules above (before) that rule in the INPUT chain which explicitly allows all traffic to that port from the IP addresses in question. iptables rules work like a waterfall, if an ALLOW rule higher in the waterfall matches, it whisks that packet off to the destination and it never makes it to rules lower in the waterfall. (And of course if it was DENY or REJECT that matches, the packet gets bounced and never makes it to any ALLOW rules lower in the waterfall).

For example:

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25461 --source 192.0.2.0 -j ALLOW

Will put a rule at the top of the waterfall chain which automatically whisks any packets from source 192.0.2.0 intended for port 25461 immediately to port 25461, without making it down to your rule that does rate limiting.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.